# putStrLn function does not accept [Char] parameter

Tags: haskell

Below code :

```
Prelude> :t putStrLn
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
Prelude> putStrLn "test"
test
it :: ()
Prelude> putStrLn "test" ++ "test"

<interactive>:25:1:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘IO ()’
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘putStrLn "test"’
    In the expression: putStrLn "test" ++ "test"
Prelude> :t "test"
"test" :: [Char]
Prelude> :t "test" ++ "test" 
"test" ++ "test" :: [Char]
Prelude>
```

I do not understand error :

```
" Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘IO ()’
        In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘putStrLn "test"’
        In the expression: putStrLn "test" ++ "test""
```

As `putStrLn` accepts a [Char] type as first parameter (I assume its implicitly converted to String ?). But this does not type check if `"test" ++ "test"` is passed as parameter, even though `"test" ++ "test"` is of type `[Char]` also ?

Comment: N.B.: There are no implicit type conversions in Haskell. `String` is just a type synonym for `[Char]`, i.e. literally the same thing. What does happen is specialisation of polymorphic values (e.g. numeric literals), but once a concrete type is picked it won't change on its own to something else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code doesn't pass `"test" ++ "test"` as a parameter. Function application binds tighter than any infix operator. Your code is parsed as

```
(putStrLn "test") ++ "test"
```

The error you get refers to the fact that `putStrLn` does not return a string.

To solve this, write

```
putStrLn ("test" ++ "test")
```

Note: `String` is defined as `type String = [Char]`, i.e. it's just a different name for the same type.

Comment: Yay for a simple answer and avoiding the temptation to talk about `IO` and its shenanigans.